# Handling a dictionary in a RetroFit response

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit for all of my API calls I am successfully getting data back and it is aligning perfectly in the Response object.

However, `pic_default` is always null when attempting to access it from the DefaultPicture class.

```
   "spaces": [
    {

        "sqft_rent": "3.00",
        "space_address_id": "spaceaddress_6RQPm9W2qzZ",
        "space_address_obscured": "University South, Palo Alto, CA",
        "space_address_lat_lng_obscured": "37.44674, -122.16930776",
        "search_rent": "3.00",
        "pic_default": {
            "width": "640",
            "height": "480",
            "url": "URL",
            "id": "pic_wmGqnkpzX5b"
        },
        "orgs": []
     }
```

In my Space.java class I have all the proper variable names and they all get assigned their correct value, however, pic_default is always null

```
String sqft_rent;
String space_address_id;
String space_address_obscured;
String space_address_lat_lng_obscured;
String search_rent;
String[] orgs;
DefaultPicture pic_default;
```

I am assuming that I am not supposed to be creating a separate object for `pic_default` What am I supposed to do instead?

Thanks

```
public class DefaultPicture {
public String getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(String width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public DefaultPicture(String width, String height, String url, String 
id) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.url = url;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

String width;
String height;
String url;
String id;
}
```

Comment: "However, pic_default is always null." You said it's null but you provide an json wih pic_default not null. Please make your question more clearly

Comment: Retrofit has nothing to do with the question. Are you using the Gson converter?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I am using the Gson converter here

Comment: Okay, then can you create a [mcve] using Gson to demonstrate the null value? https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples

Comment: Also, you seem to be missing a default empty constructor in your `DefaultPicture` class

Comment: @WillJamieson You have a constructor with arguments in the `DefaultPicture` class, this may cause the Gson can not init your object because missing the default constructor with no arguments. Please remove it and try again.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen worked like a champ thanks